# How to create a new folder from a terminal with administrative permissions?

Tags: command-line, directory

I want to install JAVA, but the installation instructions ask me to create a new folder, called `/java/`, into the standard `/usr/` folder.

But this folder is blocked. I mean, I can not to create a new folder on it, with the PCManFM file manager, because that option is grey.

So I guess there should be a command to create it from a Terminal session. (With `sudo`, maybe?)

How can I get it? Which is the right command to get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to address two parts of your question: java installation and folder creation.

**Java installation**

We already have a question about that: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56104/295286).All of the necessary commands are there, and I strongly suggest you read their manual pages with `man COMMAND` in terminal.

There's also open-source version of Java, Open JDK. Installation of that is somewhat simpler

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin
```

That's pretty much it - apt-get will take care of everything. When you install some package with `apt-get` or `dpkg` there should be preinstall and postinstall scripts that come along with the package, and run automatically to set up whatever program you're getting.

**Folder Creation**

Folder ( in linux terminology - directory ) creation, just like file creation, depends on the permissions. If a folder has the following permissions,

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 testuser  testuser   4096 Nov 22 12:34 testuser/
```

that means the owner of that folder `testuser` can read-write-execute stuff there (first `rwx`), and group `testuser` can only read and execute stuff there - that's the `r-x` part, and final `r-x` part means read execute for any other groups or users.

`/usr` folder is owned by root user, so only root can write there, that means create files or folder. Hence for that you need `sudo` to gain root privileges temporarily.

Answer (score 26):

Create the folder from a command line terminal using:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/java
```

You need `sudo` to make changes to `/usr` because `/usr` is owned by the `root` user.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Can you elaborate on why `sudo` , though ?

Comment: @Serg the folder `/usr` is owned by `root:root`, so you need root privileges to modify it

Comment: @zwork  <.< I know, with 22k rep  I already know that. I'm trying to push people to improve their answers  here

Comment: @Serg sorry, didn't check your profile

Comment: @zwork it's all good  ^_^  I probably should have worded differently my first comment

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices:

- `gksudo pcmanfm` will request you enter your password, then open PCManFM **as root**, which is somewhat dangerous because if you are not careful you may unintentionally modify system files.
- `sudo mkdir /usr/java` will create the directory directly.

Comment: I know what OP uses PCManFM , but this is still Ubuntu and there's still Nautilus, and nautilus has `nautilus-admin` for right clicking and opening file/directory with admin privileges. You might want to include that into your answer

Comment: @Serg I've never heard of `nautilus-admin` and I don't have `nautilus` on this box to test it so I won't include that because I have no idea what it is.

Comment: In my laptop, I use Lubuntu 15.10 and it doesn't have Nautilus. The file manager of Lubuntu is PCManFM. In my desktop PC, I use Ubuntu Studio 15.10 and it doesn't have Nautilus. The File manager of Ubuntu Studio is Thunar.

Answer (score 1):

```
Creates folders and files

mkdir -p ~/example(Folder)/text(Folder)
touch ~/example(folders)/text(Folder)/text{1..420}.txt
chmod -R 757 ~/example (folder with rights)


Move the text to another created folder

mkdir -p /Sturrage/V1Tst/Memes
mv ~/example/text/text{1..125}.txt /Sturrage/V1Tst/Memes


Same thing but with another folder to put all the text files that are left behind and with rights and user.

mkdir -p /V1Tst/Trash
cp ~/example/text/* /V1Tst/Trash
chmod -R 727 /V1Tst
chown -R user:group /V1Tst
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail to make it a rock solid answer.